# How to adjust NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail to a portion of NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsattributedstring

I want to adjust NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail to a portion of NSAttributedString.

For example,
The result is below.

"abcde...LAST"

The 'abcde...' is a NSAttributedString with the properties different with that of 'LAST'.
Actually, I can do if 'abcde...' string object and 'LAST' string object are diffrent.
But, I want to make to same string object.

sample code is below.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style1 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style2 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style2 setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"abcdefghijklm"];
[attrString1 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]];

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"LAST"];
[attrString2 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]];

[attrString1 appendAttributedString:attrString2];
```

Then, I expected like the third line.
But the result is like this.

"abcdefghij..."

Comment: I entered the 'enter' before 'Actually' word. :s
I don't know why that doesn't entred new-line.